# How do I know the depth of "k" for characterising set when testing FSM?

Tags: testing, finite-state-machine

I am supposed to design the tests for state machine software. I have covered all states and all transitions. The last step is to detect the hidden states (states that look the same but internally might be different, e.g. overflown buffers) using the tests designed with characterising set *W*. I have no idea how to determine the depth "*k*" and derive the set. Search did not bring any help, just generic explanation.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for our sister site [sqa.se]

Comment: "k" sounds like a name very specific to the textbooks you are using.